# How to determine closest CGPoint with an angle and another CGPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, angle

I calculate angle between two CGPoints :

```
//calculate radian and degree
            CGPoint diff = ccpSub(center, location);//return ccp(v1.x - v2.x, v1.y - v2.y);
            float rads = atan2f( diff.y, diff.x);
            float degs = -CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(rads);
            NSLog(@"Rad %.2f Degs %.2f",rads,degs);
```

Now In another function where I have a pre known CGPoint and  the degree of above function, I want to calculate closest point that satisfies the degree.

I was thinking about maybe below code would help me but in below code start point and rotation point is known, in my situation I only know start point.

```
-(void) rotateAroundPoint:(CGPoint)rotationPoint angle:(CGFloat)angle {
    CGFloat x = cos(CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-angle)) * (self.position.x-rotationPoint.x) - sin(CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-angle)) * (self.position.y-rotationPoint.y) + rotationPoint.x;
    CGFloat y = sin(CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-angle)) * (self.position.x-rotationPoint.x) + cos(CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-angle)) * (self.position.y-rotationPoint.y) + rotationPoint.y;
```

**Lets say I have a point 800,600 and I have a degree of 70, how can I calculate closest point with that point and that degree?**

EDIT:::

Normally in my game sprites are moved with a button therefore all rotation,movement,speed etc are handled when button pressed `[sprite moveToPreGivenPostion:CGPoint]`

But now a compass is added and when user choose an angle on the compass I need to move the sprite in the direction of degree on compass, since `[sprite moveToPreGivenPostion:CGPoint]` already handles rotation and other stuff I just want to determine that what CGPoint should I send to `moveToPreGivenPostion` function.

Comment: I don't understand this. What's "the closest point"? Why is the calculation you presented in the first part isn't good enough?

Comment: The closest point to the point you are given with the parameters you specify is either right on top of the original point, or it is an infinitely small (and unmeasurable) distance away in the direction of your angle (in real space, and even in floating point space).

Comment: @H2CO3 I have edited question with  more details and why I am trying to do this.

Comment: After reading your edit, I still dont understand how your question is applicable to your problem?  How are they choosing the angle, how are you drawing the compass?  Dont you have defined movement speed that can define your second point based upon current position plus speed in the compass defined direction?

Comment: @trumpetlicks yes technically you are right what I mean is if 400,400 is a CGPoint, and the closest point with an 135 angle would be 401,401. I hope that is clear enough for you?

Comment: @MordFustang - All you need to do is simply define a movement RADIUS, and calculate your new point to move to from your current point + 1*radius in the direction of your compass.  This will give you constant speed.  You dont need the "closest" point.

Comment: @trumpetlicks  `point + 1*radius in the direction of your compass`  thats the part I couldnt make it. how should I use this in a function, could you show an example of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @trumpetlicks said you cant find the closest point like that, but I guess I understood what you want and that function `-(void) rotateAroundPoint:(CGPoint)rotationPoint angle:(CGFloat)angle` you are trying to use is perfectly fine to achieve what you want.

[image]

all you need to do is choose float radius.

you know your current point and lets say your radius is 1, basically you can calculate your previous point without a degree, assuming `0` degrees is left of your point and lets say your point is 200,200 with 1 radius 0 degree your previous point automatically becomes 199,200. 
So now you have a reference point so now calculate the point you want to move your sprite:

```
//choose a feasable radius
    float radius = 0.5;
    //position_ is your preknown position as you said
    //find a the point to roate 
    //position_.x-radius is always 0 degrees of your current point
    CGFloat x = cos(rads) * ((position_.x-radius)-position_.x) - sin(rads) * ((position_.y)-position_.y) + position_.x;
    CGFloat y = sin(rads) * ((position_.x-radius)-position_.x) + cos(rads) * ((position_.y)-position_.y) + position_.y;

    //get the new point
    CGPoint newLocation = ccp(x, y);
```